# Returning the paths of top level of directories in Python: Comparing two solutions

Tags: python, algorithm, directory

After doing some searching on how to return paths of top level folders only in python, I've found two fairly different approaches that seem to return identical results:

```
def listTopDirs(folder):
    return [name for name in (os.path.join(folder, each) for each in os.listdir(folder)) if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

Vs.

```
def listTopDirs():
    return [os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]
```

These return the same number of results for me when I try them out on my machine.

Would either be considered more pythonic?  Is there any algorithmic advantage to using one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

Although the second snippet seems more Pythonic to me, a quick speed test proved that the first snippet was quicker. I posted the results below.

---

```
def listTopDirs(folder):
    return [name for name in (os.path.join(folder, each) for each in os.listdir(folder)) if os.path.isdir(name)]

$ python -m timeit 'import os;r = [name for name in (os.path.join(".", each) for each in os.listdir(".")) if os.path.isdir(name)]'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.59 msec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.60 msec per loop
```

---

```
def listTopDirs():
    return [os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]

$ python -m timeit 'import os;r = [os.path.abspath(name) for name in os.listdir(".") if os.path.isdir(name)]'
100 loops, best of 3: 4.54 msec per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.54 msec per loop
```